# Падение приложения при закрытии клавиатуры

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-edittext, клавиатура

Открываю клавиатуру, пишу название упражнения и время и добавляю `Item` с этими данными в `RecyclerView`. Cразу же после этого, если я закрываю клавиатуру, то крашится приложение с вот такой ошибкой.

> Reason: Input dispatching timed out 
>           Activity.Training.ConstructorTwoPartActivity, Waiting to send non-key event 
>           because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events 
>           that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 14.  Wait 
>           queue head age: 5582.1ms.)

Хотя, если я просто впишу данные в `EditText` и не нажму "+", т.е. не добавлю `Item`, то все прекрасно закрывается. Вот файл разметки этого активити.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    tools:context=".ViewTC.Activity.Training.ConstructorTwoPartActivity"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    <!--TODO style-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardioExerciceAlreadyReady"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/main_background_two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:cardElevation="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/nameCardioBut"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name_cardio"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_light_gray"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light_gray"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/timeCardioBut"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/time_cardio"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_light_gray"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light_gray"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCardio"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radiusbutton"
            android:text="@string/add_plus"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_account_white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textWeight"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_light_gray"
                android:textColor="@color/text_light_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/weight_two"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_light_gray"
                android:textColor="@color/text_light_gray" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCardio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, когда я не открываю клавиатуру и добавляю надписи иконками (над полями ввода , рис. 2), то все отлично работает и `Item` добавляются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score -1):

решил проблему. Приложение даже не должно было компиляцию проходить с такой ошибкой. но почему то проходило. дело в моей невнимательности.
Проблема была в том что я обьявил кастомное вью EditText где я изменил некоторые параметры, а непосредственно в коде указал обычный EditText, из за этого в некоторые моменты приложение крашилось, но почему то не сразу, и почему то как то компилятор пропустил эту ошибку.

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно решили проблему, опишите в чем именно она заключалась, чтобы другие пользователи с аналогичной проблемой могли решить ее быстрее. В текущем виде ваше сообщение никак не является ответом и не несет никакой полезной информации.